# Upload APK File to Google Play using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, google-play, casperjs

I need to create a script that uploads for the first time a APK file to Google Play (their API only allows to upload APKs after the first version has been published).

Here is the script I have so far:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.read('test.cookies');
phantom.cookies = JSON.parse(data);

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var casper = require('casper').create({   
    //verbose: true, 
    //logLevel: 'debug',
    stepTimeout: 60000,
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  false,
        loadPlugins: false,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    }
});

casper.start().thenOpen('https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=14088528817615018970', function() {
    if (this.getCurrentUrl().indexOf('accounts.google.com') == -1) {
        // cookies working
        this.bypass(3);
    } else {
        console.log('sign in page opened!')
    }
});

casper.then(function() {
    console.log('populating form with email');

    this.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector('input#Email').value = "email@address.com";
        document.querySelector('input#next').click();
    });
})

casper.waitForSelector("input#Email-hidden", function() {
    console.log('populating form with password');

    this.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector('input#Passwd').value = "passwd";
        document.querySelector('input#signIn').click();
    });
})

//Wait to be redirected to the Home page, and then make a screenshot
casper.then(function(){
  console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());

    var cookies = JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies);
    fs.write('test.cookies', cookies, 644);
});

// Google play page
casper.then(function() {
  console.log('Current page: ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.waitForSelector(".BVO4BTD-b-a.BVO4BTD-b-o.BVO4BTD-Be-a", function() {
    console.log('Add new app');

    this.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector('.BVO4BTD-b-a.BVO4BTD-b-o.BVO4BTD-Be-a').click();
    });
});

casper.waitForSelector(".BVO4BTD-hj-a", function() {
    console.log('Filling form');
    this.capture('5.png',{
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: 500,
      height: 400
  });

    this.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector('.BVO4BTD-hj-a > input.gwt-TextBox').value = "App Teste";
        document.querySelector('.BVO4BTD-g-K .BVO4BTD-b-a.BVO4BTD-b-o').click();
    });
});

casper.waitForSelector(".BVO4BTD-gg-a .BVO4BTD-b-a.BVO4BTD-b-o", function() {
    this.capture('6.png',{
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: 500,
      height: 400
  });
  console.log('Current page: ' + this.getCurrentUrl());

  console.log('Click for app upload');
  this.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector(".BVO4BTD-gg-a .BVO4BTD-b-a.BVO4BTD-b-o").click();
  });
});

casper.waitForSelector(".BVO4BTD-Re-b.BVO4BTD-g-U.BVO4BTD-d-b", function() {

    this.capture('7.png',{
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: 500,
      height: 400
  });

    /**/


  this.evaluate(function() {
      document.querySelector(".BVO4BTD-Re-b.BVO4BTD-g-U.BVO4BTD-d-b .BVO4BTD-b-a.BVO4BTD-b-m").click();
      casper.page.uploadFile(".BVO4BTD-Re-b.BVO4BTD-g-U.BVO4BTD-d-b input[type=file]", '/path/to/apk/file.apk');
    });

    this.wait(3000, function() {
        this.capture('8.png',{
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: 500,
          height: 400
      });
  });
});

casper.run(function() {
    console.log('end');
});
```

These steps already work:

- Sign In at Google Play (saves a cookie, so it skips this part)
- Creates an app named `App Teste`
- Goes to Upload APK screen

I can't make the upload script work, I guess there is a lot of javascript behind Google Play's upload mechanism.

My attempt to upload happens on the last `waitForSelector` section.

Thank you.

Comment: `evaluate` is sandboxed. You cannot use `casper` inside of it.

Comment: I'm trying to do that same thing, and I'm having the same problem. My upload hangs at 0%.

Answer (score 1):

`casper.page` is actually just a phantomjs WebPage object, and probably shouldn't be used inside of the `this.evaluate`.

To accomplish the same goal, you can try:

```
casper.waitForSelector(".form-selector", function() {
  // your capture code
  casper.page.uploadFile('selector', '/path/to/file');
});

casper.then(function() {
  // whatever you need to do after file upload
});
```

Also, to fill out the forms, you can try `casper.fill()`.

Sources: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#then (casper), http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html (phantomjs)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following script it might work
Note: where 'filename' is the path of the file from your local directory.

`var filename = /home/xyz/android/file_you_want_to_upload.apk`

```
casper.then(function () {
        this.evaluate(function (fileName) {
            __utils__.findOne('input[type="file"]').setAttribute('value', fileName)
        }, {fileName: fileName});
        this.page.uploadFile('input[type="file"]', fileName);
        console.log('Selecting a file');
    });
    casper.then(function () {
        console.log("Clicking on Upload ");
        this.click(x("xpath of upload button"));
    });
```